# Joomla error. Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server

Tags: joomla

I see this error when open my site home page.
http://dis-industrial.com/

> Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server
>   or _session or globals passed to script.

I saw questions on site for the same error and none of them applies to my site situation.

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using? Which ever version it is, please firstly ensure it's up to date >> **(1.5.26 or 2.5.14 or 3.1.5)**

Comment: i do not know; I am migrating this site. how can i know this info?

Comment: There was a similar question several days ago. Also an IIS7 server. Do you possess PHP skills? Perhaps it could help resolve both of your issues.

Comment: the site is hosted on go-daddy windows servers. with iis7. and I have average php skills.

Comment: It's not a PHP error, it's a Joomla based one. I can't even tell which version you're using as the admin panel is also getting the error. Open an XML file such as `modules/mod_articles_archive/mod_articles_archive.xml` and on line 2, it will say `version="XX"`.

Comment: I know, but the Joomla error is uninformative. I consider adding some code to help identify the culprit variable that causes this.

Comment: The joomla version is "1.5.0"

Comment: @Lodder, this originates from `/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php` of J1.5 (or pre-2.5, at least). My guess is that IIS creates some request variables that causes this test to fail.

Comment: @user2699452 - ensure you're running the latest version of the 1.5 series 1.5.26

Comment: @user2699452, It appears that you have resolved the issue. Can you explain what was wrong? I am under the impression that others have experienced the same thing.

Comment: i did not. i moved to Linux hosting.