# Joomla Site Won't Load When Accessed From a Search Engine

Tags: php, joomla, search-engine, referrer

My site loads fine when accessed directly http://www.holidayexpress.org/

However, when accessing the site via a search engine such as Google or Bing, it fails to load and gives only this message:

> Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server
>   or _session or globals passed to script.

I have researched the message but wasn't able to find any solutions.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this or what's causing it?

I have also compared the HTTP requests and I notice the only difference seems to be the `Referrer` header:

```
Host:www.holidayexpress.org
Referer:http://www.bing.com/search?q=holiday+express&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=holiday+express&sc=8-15&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=e26b4f1500b4420eae67e6914a8bfa33
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36
```

Again, when accessed directly, it works fine.  But, if you try to access it via a search engine it won't work!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I cannot access your site ;) Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script. So i think its a normal problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356683/joomla-error-illegal-variable-files-or-env-or-get-or-post-or-cookie-or-s

Comment: @Lodder I have found that exact answer but it doesn't say how to fix the problem, it just says why it happens.  Do you have an actual solution that I can use to solve the problem?

Comment: I would start by changing the source to log/display the offending variable, as this error is too general. I mentioned the file that throws this error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444871/joomla-error-illegal-variable-files-or-env-or-get-or-post-or-cookie-or-se#comment27103861_18444871).

Answer (score 1):

This has been already answered. Please check the links below.

[Joomla error: 'Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356683/joomla-error-illegal-variable-files-or-env-or-get-or-post-or-cookie-or-s)

[Joomla error. Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444871/joomla-error-illegal-variable-files-or-env-or-get-or-post-or-cookie-or-se)

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2328766

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/ckforms/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=17458

Comment: I have already found that answer but it isn't an answer.  It just explains why it happens but doesn't say how to fix it.  Am I missing something?